# Cisco ASA 5506 log collection after power cycle

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, network, networking

Today we had to power cycle our Cisco ASA 5506 , since I could not connect to it through any of the connected interfaces.

How can I get the logs to see what failed or what was the state of the ASA before the power cycle?

Thanks an advance!

Alvaro Lamadrid

Comment: Did you look at the logs on the syslog server you have configured in the ASA to send its logs?

Comment: @RonMaupin thank you for your reply. We dont have a Syslog server in place , can the logs be found locally on the ASA?

Comment: Did you configure _any_ logging? Most likely, any information that was in the ASA is gone after you reloaded it. Cisco has a lot of was to save logging information, from SNMP traps to syslog servers, but if you did not configure any, then I do not see how we can help you.

Comment: Thank you @RonMaupin, I have not configured any of those logging services on the Cisco ASA , I was wondering if just like Windows and Linux , the ASA would have a locally available method to check the logs. So , this means that in order to get logs from the Cisco ASA you must configure one of this network services? (SNMP or Syslog)

Comment: It will log to the level you have configured in an internal buffer, but I doubt that survives a reload. You can try `sh log` to see what is in the buffer.

Comment: Thank you for your help @RonMaupin, I'll make sure I take a deeper look into ASA logging options, is there any specific documentation or tutorial you can recommend me?

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic for SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se]. You can search for `cisco asa logging` and you will find that Cisco maintains a library of documentation on all its devices.

Comment: Perfect, I didnt mean to brake the StackExchange rules with my question, thank you again , have a great day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If persistent logging was not configured (syslog, local file, serial console, etc.), then the logs will be lost upon reload or power cycle. Unlike Windows (eventlog) or Linux (syslog, journalD), this is NOT an automatic process. If you didn't take steps to collect and store the information, it doesn't get collected or stored.